# System font won't show Light or UltraLight weights on some devices

Tags: ios, swift, fonts

I have a UIPickerView that I want to use a monospaced system font. I'm using the pickerView(_:viewForRow:...) delegate method to define the view for a row, that view has a label, and I'm setting the label font like this:

```
pickerLabel.font = UIFont.monospacedDigitSystemFont(ofSize: 50, weight: .ultraLight)
```

On some devices, such as my test device, this works fine:

[image: UltraLight System Font]

But on other devices, such as this one from an iPhone 5S, the font is not the correct weight:

[image: System font with incorrect weight]

this happens on devices of larger screen sizes (such as iPhone 6) as well.

Does anyone know what's going on here? I've seen answers about similar issues saying that UltraLight doesn't exist for sizes smaller than 20, but this is size 50.

Also, the same issue happens with a weight of Light. Heavy, however, DOES work on these other devices!

The devices are running iOS versions from 10.3.3 and up (some 11.4, some lower, but none lower than 10.3.3).

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Good question. Some clarification questions that might be helpful. (1) Your test device - what is it? Also, I'm assuming it's the first screenshot. (2) These *"other"* devices (such as the second screenshot and iPhone6)... real or simulated? (3) I get we are talking a range of both devices and iOS versions, but since it might matter, what are the specifics? I **really** don't think this last detail matters but you never know. I'm already assuming you've taken into account screen resolutions, etc. So yeah, my questions probably won't help.

Comment: My test device in the first screenshot (where the weight is correct) is an iPhone 7 running iOS 11.4. The second device is an iPhone 5S running iOS 10.3.3. Both are physical devices. This isn't a matter of screen resolutions, as we've seen this on identical screens (such as iPhone 6). I'm thinking it might have something to do with the user setting the font size on their device or something like that, but I couldn't figure it out (testing different settings for font size in Settings -> Display & Brightness -> Text Size didn't change anything).